# UNNotificationAttachment with UIImage or Remote URL

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, unnotificationserviceextension, unnotificationattachment

In my `Notification Service Extension` I am downloading an image from a URL to show as `UNNotificationAttachment` in a notification.

So I have this image as UIImage and don't see the need to write it in my app directory / group container on disc just to set up the notification.

**Is there a good way create an `UNNotificationAttachment` with a UIImage ?**
(should be appliable to local and remote notifications)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. create directory in tmp folder
2. write the `NSData` representation of the `UIImage` into the newly created directory
3. create the UNNotificationAttachment with url to the file in tmp folder
4. clean up tmp folder

I wrote an extension on `UINotificationAttachment`

```
extension UNNotificationAttachment {

    static func create(identifier: String, image: UIImage, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let tmpSubFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let tmpSubFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(tmpSubFolderName, isDirectory: true)
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: tmpSubFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let imageFileIdentifier = identifier+".png"
            let fileURL = tmpSubFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
            let imageData = UIImage.pngData(image)
            try imageData()?.write(to: fileURL)
            let imageAttachment = try UNNotificationAttachment.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
            return imageAttachment
        } catch {
            print("error " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

So to create `UNUserNotificationRequest` with `UNUserNotificationAttachment` from a `UIImage` you can simply do sth like this

```
let identifier = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Hello"
content.body = "World"
if let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.create(identifier: identifier, image: myImage, options: nil) {
    // where myImage is any UIImage
    content.attachments = [attachment] 
}
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 120.0, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
    // handle error
}
```

This should work since `UNNotificationAttachment` will copy the image file to an own location.

Comment: I do not see "Step 4 clean up tmp folder"

Comment: How would you approach the step 4, removing the temp folder? Right after the notification has been opened?

Comment: Temp folder is used which is cleaned up by the system automatically its the cache directory that isn't cleaned up

Comment: Your extension does have an extra closing bracket. It won't compile.

Comment: Why we have to create new directory / file? When I try to rewrite the file, it alwyas fails.

Comment: Note that iOS automatically moves the file into the attachment data store, so this file will be deleted from the temporary directory right away. You don't need to worry about clean up.

Answer (score 6):

I've created a blogpost on this subject, focused on GIF images. But it should be easy to rewrite my code for simply images.

You need to create a Notification Service Extension:
[image: Notification Service Extension]

And include this code:

```
final class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    private var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    private var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override internal func didReceiveNotificationRequest(request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: (UNNotificationContent) -> Void){
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        func failEarly() {
            contentHandler(request.content)
        }

        guard let content = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent) else {
            return failEarly()
        }

        guard let attachmentURL = content.userInfo["attachment-url"] as? String else {
            return failEarly()
        }

        guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string: attachmentURL)!) else { return failEarly() }
        guard let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.create("image.gif", data: imageData, options: nil) else { return failEarly() }

        content.attachments = [attachment]
        contentHandler(content.copy() as! UNNotificationContent)
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}

extension UNNotificationAttachment {

    /// Save the image to disk
    static func create(imageFileIdentifier: String, data: NSData, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let tmpSubFolderName = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString
        let tmpSubFolderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(tmpSubFolderName, isDirectory: true)

        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(tmpSubFolderURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = tmpSubFolderURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
            try data.writeToURL(fileURL!, options: [])
            let imageAttachment = try UNNotificationAttachment.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, URL: fileURL!, options: options)
            return imageAttachment
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error)")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

For more information you can check my blogpost here:
http://www.avanderlee.com/ios-10/rich-notifications-ios-10/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [answer] for more details.

Comment: @VinceBowdren you're totally right. Changed my answer!

Comment: and when do you remove images from temp directory?

Comment: The system prunes the temporary directory itself.

Comment: It seems to be in att-url and not in attachment-url ;-)

Comment: It seems that we have to use the same "normal" file extension like ".jpg" for jpeg files and ".png" etc for png and so on. It's not enough to just use a generic filename like "myfile" without extension. I'm assuming this is a weakness of UNNotificationAttachment or `someplace`. https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/15555

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example how to actually download an image from internet and attach it to a local notification (which is part of the original question).

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "This is a test"
content.body = "Just checking the walls"

if let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/images/example.png") {

    let pathExtension = url.pathExtension

    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (result, response, error) in
        if let result = result {

            let identifier = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString                
            let target = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(identifier).appendingPathExtension(pathExtension)

            do {
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: result, to: target)

                let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: identifier, url: target, options: nil)
                content.attachments.append(attachment)

                let notification = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: Date().description, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notification, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Normally there is no need to recreate the image when the downloaded file already is a valid image. Just copy the downloaded file to the current Temp directory with a unique name and a `.png` or `.jpg` extension. It's also not necessary to create a sub directory in the existing Temp directory.

Answer (score 0):

From `UIImage` it seems that it is not possible, all the solutions that I found were downloading the image and store it somewhere locally. Also makes sense because you would have to import `UIKit` and not sure if it is compatible with extensions (and why import a whole framework when there are simpler solutions).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58538872/8483739) is a simpler and testable solution and without the need of using a FileManager.