# Cannot attach media in remote notification using notification service extension in ios 10

Tags: ios, swift, unnotificationrequest

I can modify the content of remote notification using
"func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, 
withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)"  of notification service extension. But could'nt download images or movies and add them as attachments to the content.

How can we attach medias in remote notification using this method.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension to simplify the process, see here:
[UNNotificationAttachment with UIImage or Remote URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103095/unnotificationattachment-with-uiimage-or-remote-url/39103096#39103096)

Then you can include the image like this

```
let identifier = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Hello"
content.body = "World"
if let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.create(identifier: identifier, image: myImage, options: nil) {
    // where myImage is any UIImage that follows the 
    content.attachments = [attachment] 
}
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 120.0, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
    // handle error
}
```