# How to do local notification in ionic 4 with capacitor that show icon and image in notification "not cordova local notification "

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

i use ionic 4 capacitor to show local notification which i found documentation on there website 
but documentations are not complete 
this is their link 
   [ionic capacitor local notification documentation](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/local-Notifications/)

It is working but i don't know how to show image and how to change the icon. 
i tried a lot of thing.

Is there anyone who tested it and can help me?

this is my code already

```
    LocalNotifications.schedule({
  notifications: [
    {
      title: "aaaa",
      body: "Body",
      id: 1,
      actionTypeId: 'OPEN_PRODUCT',
      attachments: [
        { id: 'face', url: 'https://khanoo.com/wp-content/uploads/estate_images/house/77-1576179614/230174.jpg' ,options:{}}
      ],
      schedule: {
        every: "minute"
      },

      extra: null
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: watch related issue on https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/issues/430

Answer (score 0):

From the code source, looks like they have some definition for `smallIcon` (but it's apparently only for Android)...

[image: LocalNotification interface]

About the image - not sure what kind of image do you want to show... 
From the definition, they have the `LocalNotificationAttachment` that can be used for iOS to show rich notifications.
It's something like this

[image: iOS Rich notifications]

Comment: thanks for reply , do you have code for LocalNotificationAttachment used to show an image on notification ? i do not know how to use that Attachment with url image.
for example i used it like this and it is not working 


` 
attachments: [
            { id: 'face', url: 'https://khanoo.com/wp-content/uploads/estate_images/house/77-1576179614/230174.jpg' }
          ], 
`

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/473a50e2e087602591891de3f4dac6eafe5d3755/core/src/core-plugin-definitions.ts#L1008

Comment: Also check this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103096/197500

Comment: Thanks but thats not helpful 
because i have this code already and it does not show image 

    LocalNotifications.schedule({
      notifications: [
        {
          title: "aaaa",
          body: "Body",
          id: 1,
          actionTypeId: 'OPEN_PRODUCT',
          attachments: [
            { id: 'face', url: 'https://khanoo.com/wp-content/uploads/estate_images/house/77-1576179614/230174.jpg' ,options:{}}
          ],
          schedule: {
            every: "minute"
          },
         
        extra: null
       }
   `  ] `
`}); `

Comment: I think you're missing the options

Comment: options is just for ios

Answer (score 0):

The related issue going on this https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/issues/430

> http/https urls are not supported by iOS (native API limitation)
>
> on Android and Web the attachments are not shown as images, should be implemented